# DotNetNuke 9.4.4 - No service for type 'DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.IModuleControlPipeline' has been registered

Tags: dotnetnuke-9

After upgrading from 9.0.2 to  9.4.4, our site now shows the following error.

> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Unhandled error loading page. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.IModuleControlPipeline' has been registered.

The site comes up properly on initialization; however, on the refresh it shows a 500 internal error.

In version 9.0.2 or less, we usually deploy our site with the publish setting "Precompile during publishing" using Visual Studio.

With this new version 9.4.4, the precompile setting seems to be generating the error mentioned above. When the precompile setting is unchecked; the error message is no longer an issue and the site seems to function properly.

I have been trying to find and implement ideas on how to resolve this error for many days now, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed .Net Framework 4.7.2 which is required for DNN 9.4.4.